# how can I use the output from find to create a variable?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want to use win32 shell and try to get a variable to receive input from the find function, so

```
set var = cscript [Location] | find /c "test"
```

then I want to use an if statement to see if the value is 1 or 0, but I can't get the first part to work and there is no one else I can find with a similar situation. Up above on the right side of the = sign I have a return value of 1 or 0 always.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('cscript "script.vbs" ^|find /c "test"') do set var=%%a
```